# How I can set different theme for the category list page?

Tags: magento2, category, layout

I want to set separate theme which is applied only for a specific page, for example, category list page only rest of the all the page has a different theme.

Answer (score 0):

Login to the Magento admin panel and navigate to Catalog > Categories and click on the specific category for which you would like to change the theme scroll down to the design tab and there you can choose your desired theme from the Theme drop-down. Refer the screenshot below:
[image]

Comment: @shail what sort of development guide are you looking for? This can be done using admin configuration.

Comment: theme implemention which called layout for only category list page

Comment: Your actual question doesn't include this information that you would like to implement it in theme layout.